# Rails fails to recognize a PUT request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Rails gives the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/32"
```

Even though the routes, view and controller is set up correctly. What I am missing?

**Environment**: Rails 3.2.12, Ruby 2.0.0p0

Routes

```
Foo::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  match '/pages/:action', controller: "pages", as: "pages"
  root to: 'pages', action: 'index'
end
```

Rake routes

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
    pages        /pages/:action(.:format)  pages#:action
     root        /                         pages#index
```

Haml

```
= form_tag "/#{@collection_name}/#{@entity.id}", :method => :put do
  ...
```

Which gets transformed into this html

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/32" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="NnD8tNkx//5o3TQWhBYxFgYGS8kG9n+7WSeA0mon9t8=">
  </div>
  ...
```

Comment: weird, nothing obvious here, are you sure all params are sent?

Comment: It looks like not all params are being passed. As you see from your rake routes output, you don't have a POST method for /users/:id path, and the `No route matches [POST] "/users/32"` error makes me think that the `_method` param doesn't get passed.

Comment: yeah, would be good to see the logs where params are listed. Also, is it sent via normal request or ajax?

Comment: @apneadiving
I've put a match-all route at the end of the routes to go to application#route_not_found and did a params inspect there. All the params seems fine, except I don't see the _method key in params hash. Should it be there?

Comment: @khustochka
normal request

    Parameters: {"commit"=>"Save user", "user"=>{<bunch of user attrs>}, "path"=>"users/32"}

Comment: Instead of the `application#route_not_found` way, can you just get the sent parameters from the error/debug page when you get the `No route matches [POST] "/users/32"` error page?

Comment: @JohnZ no params are shown on the routing error page, only the routing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a show user page which renders a form with disabled inputs where all the user data is shown.

There's a button to enable all fields and allow editing the user. This button is handled by some JavaScript code and it toggles the "disabled" attribute on all form input elements.

Since the `_method` and all magic Rails form attributes are also inputs, my JavaScript code put a `disabled` attribute on them because they didn't have one.

**The lesson**: DO NOT PROCESS ALL FORM INPUTS WITH JAVASCRIPT, RAILS DEPENDS ON SOME OF THEM.

Comment: So now you can reach the route POST /users/:id which doesn't exist? :)

Comment: @rorra the problem was not in reaching the POST route, but in the fact that Rails failed to recognize that I am making a PUT request. The reason that happened is because I disabled the input element in the form which tells Rails that my request is a PUT one. A disabled input in a form doesn't get included in the form data upon submission, therefore Rails couldn't have any idea of the method the for m is supposed to use (besides that it is a POST one)

Comment: @rorra It's not a POST now. It's a PUT because the `_method` param gets passed and Rails process the request as a PUT one, which exists in routes.